# Nietzsche's departure from Schopenhauer

Tags: ethics, nietzsche, nihilism, schopenhauer

I'm attempting to understand the will to power by first presenting Nietzsche's first mentor, Schopenhauer, and his notion of the will to survival/life.

In very simple terms, I believe S believed that life is a constant state of suffering followed by a short period of happiness followed by more suffering, etc. To deal with this, S thought it's best to lead an ascetic lifestyle and to become compassionate to other suffering humans as well as animals.
N agreed that ultimately existence is driven by a will to life, which he calls "will to power." But he rejects S's morality because it might lead to nihilism.

This is my attempt at fully understanding what the will to power is, thus it would help me greatly to receive some feedback on my understanding N's departure from S prior to defining the will to power.

Is it simply that N rejected S's morality of compassion because a) it suppresses some of our natural and healthy desires; and b) it may lead one to live a nihilist life?

Comment: Some people who come here may have a good answer for you, but they may not have the time to answer a relatively big question like this. Don't despair. You can find books and journal articles on such topics at a good library.